# Сохранение цвета текста

Tags: java, android

Надо сохранить измененный цвет нескольких букв. Я создал слайд текстов с помощью массива, проблема в том что при переходе на другой текст или при клике назад, измененный цвет пропадает. Надо что бы  цвет остался. Можете подсказать что делать.

Вот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] mTestArray;
int texts = 0;
int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTestArray =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    ImageButton prev = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);


    final TextView tex = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

    final Spannable text = new SpannableString(mTestArray[2]);
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, 18,  SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tex.setText(text);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(texts == mTestArray.length-1 ){
                texts=0;
            }else {
                texts++;
            }
            tex.setText(mTestArray[texts]);
        }
    });
    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(texts == 0){
                tex.setText(mTestArray[0]);
            }else {
                texts--;
            }
            tex.setText(mTestArray[texts]);
        }
    });}

}
```

string.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">ArrayTextColor2</string>
    <string name="slidestring">Slide</string>
    <string-array name="colors">
        <item>I read the letter. Stood up. Sat down.  Pondered for a minute. Then reread the letter again.
            Я прочитал письмо. Встал. Сел. Поразмышлял минуту. Потом еще раз перечитал письмо.</item>
        <item>It is only with the heart that one can see rightly.
По-настоящему можно видеть только сердцем.</item>
        <item>One can become a writer only if he is talented.
Писателем может стать только тот, у кого есть талант.</item>
        <item>They say, the winter will be cold.
Говорят, зима будет холодной.</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете сохранять цвет в SharedPreference(http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html) или базу данных. Но в данном случае я думаю лучше в SharedPreference. 
И теперь в OnResume достаете эти данные(если они сохранены) и красите текст в нужные цвета. А как только где-то изменился цвет, то кладете его в SharedPreference. Таким образом, у вас будет сохраняться каждое изменение текста.